# Two web project in my solution which one to deploy

Tags: asp.net, azure, bitbucket

I have a solution structured like this

```
Proj.Soln
    Proj.Api.csproj
    Proj.Web.csproj
```

I have configured microsoft azure with bitbucket.org. When I commit through git to bitbucket, azure will pick this up and deploy my application. How do I specify that I want Proj.Web.csproj deployed and not Proj.Api.csproj?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether there is another method to chose the project, but are some steps to help you achieve your goal (note: this is tested and confirmed to be working):

- Configure the Continuous Deployment for your WebSite to your Git repository (BitBucket)
- Make initial commit to make sure the configuration is fine and working
- Connect to your site via FTP (if unsure how, [here is tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2012/06/19/windows-azure-website-uploading-downloading-files-over-ftp-and-collecting-diagnostics-logs.aspx))
- Navigate to the following folder in FTP: `/site/deployments/tools` - note that this folder might be hidden. If so, just type it in your FTP client software
- In that folder you will see `deploy.cmd` file
- download that file (`deploy.cmd`)
- open the file to edit it with your favorite text edit tool
- there are two lines with `msbuild.exe` that instruct which project to be build (`MyProjectfolder\MyProject.csproj`)
- change the correct path for your other project, and do not forget that the other project is also in another folder (i.e. `MyOtherProjectFolder\MyOtherProject.csproj`)
- save the `deploy.cmd`
- upload the edited `deploy.cmd` and overwrite the old one under `/site/deployments/tools`
- commit a new change to your original source code repository on BitBucket
- have a cup of coffee and enjoy the result!

Comment: I have similar problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26891399/azure-website-continuous-deployment-always-picks-up-the-wrong-project), and my /site/deployments folder is empty. What can I do?