# Azure Website Continuous Deployment always picks up the wrong project

Tags: azure, tfs, continuous-integration, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs

I have the following folder structure in my TFS online:

[image]

The folder names also match the project names in the solution.

Legend:

- green dot: web api 2.0 project
- red dot: class library
- blue dot: console app added as a webjob to the web project
- grey dot: console app only used for testing

Working folders for build definition:
[image]

The build definition was created automatically by connecting Azure to TFS online, and I have only changed the folder, so instead of the Team Project root folder, it points to the folder of this branch, containing the solution file and the folders in the first picture.

(This points to the folder which contains the solution files as well as all the subfolders from the first image.

**Problem:**
When I run a build, it always picks up the `ExpiringRateCardsWorker` project (even now the `Web` project has been renamed (both the directory and the project file) to start with an underscore, so it will be first alphabetically.

The deployment is successful, this is what I see in Monaco:

[image]

How can I make it pick up the web project?

**Edit:** Question was closed stating to be the duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24947317/two-web-project-in-my-solution-which-one-to-deploy). I have since tried the solution suggested there, but the `/site/deployments` folder is empty on the FTP, it doesn't contain the `deploy.cmd`, so my question is still not answered unfortunatelly.

Comment: how did you try to access /site/deployments? also, my guess is this folder will only be created after first real deployment. Thus, if your deployment always fails, there will no be such folder and file.

Comment: And thank you for the downvote - very kind of you!

Comment: I accessed it via FTP. Deployments folder is there, and the deployment is successful, as I indicated in my post... only problem is that it's the wrong project, it's the console app (webjob). Apologies for the downvote, but you have closed my question by ponting to an unuseful answer, and I was under the impression downvoting is an appropriate way to mark unuseful answers. Please edit your answer (any edit since my vote is locked) and I'm happy to remove it, I had no intention to insult you.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that question as VSO does not go through the same flow as GitHub/Bitbucket deployments.

Comment: Did you try adding an App Setting named 'Project' in the website, with the value pointing to the csproj file of your web project?

Answer (score 1):

I'm experiencing similar problem with deployment of MVC application to Azure using CD in VSO. 
This problem is somehow related to WebJob Publishing mechanism.

For now I wasn't able to deploy my whole solution with WebJob in one go, but when I've deleted all webjob *.json files and [Microsoft WebJobs Publish](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish/1.0.2) NuGet package from my solution, I've managed to deploy my MVC App normally.

I think I'll have to deploy this parts of the application separately, for now.